# Ubuntu 18.04 reboot unexpectly

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm new to Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 reboots unexpectedly.  This happens regularly once a day about 10 mins after first booting the system.

I have checked `cron` and `anacron`, and don't see anything related to rebooting. Personally, I never use `cron` or `anacron` for scheduled jobs.

I have also been monitoring `/var/log/syslog` on boot. Before the reboot occurs, it shows nothing wrong.  Recently I tried to press <kbd>sysrq</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to force the system to renew the syslog. After doing this, I usually get the following result in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar  8 17:34:44 reason-NB50TJ1-TK1 kernel: [ 2450.063751] sysrq: Emergency Sync
Mar  8 17:34:44 reason-NB50TJ1-TK1 kernel: [ 2450.063878] Emergency Sync complete
```

However if I press <kbd>sysrq</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>  just before the reboot (about 9 mins after boot), it shows nothing. It looks like the log will stop renewing just before the reboot.

I don't think any hardware problems exist because I dual boot Windows 10 and it runs smoothly without any errors. I installed `i3wm` and `tlp`.  Perhaps this is causing the conflict?

P.S. I tried the original Gnome, it showed a dialog like "A software problem detected, report?". Then (about 9 mins later) I continued my <kbd>sysrq</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> trying and the /var/log/syslog did not respond. At last it rebooted again.

P.S.2 Now I know how to reproduce this problem:

1. Boot into Windows 10
2. Reboot into Ubuntu without poweroff

Then Ubuntu will always crash about 10 mins later.